# eventlet thread not printing the output

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, eventlet

I am new to python threading, trying out eventlet threads, i wrote a simple program which calculates squares and cube of a number and issuing two eventlet threads on it. my code is as below:

```
    import eventlet
    eventlet.monkey_patch()
    def square(num):
        print "square={}".format(num*num)
    def cube(num):
        print "square={}".format(num*num*num)
    t1 = eventlet.spawn_n(square, 10)
    t2 = eventlet.spawn_n(cube, 10)
```

The above code is excuting but not printing the output? Can you please suggest me on where i am going wrong, do i need to add a "wait" satatement in the code?

Answer (score 1):

So, Evenlets are deamons, which means that if the core code stops the threads stop aswel.
If you want to wait, you should work with the event class:

```
import eventlet
from threading import Event
eventlet.monkey_patch()

se=Event()
def square(num):
    print(    "square={}".format(num * num))
    se.set()

sc=Event()
def cube(num):
    print(  "square={}".format(num * num * num))
    sc.set()

t1 = eventlet.spawn_n(square, 10)
t2 = eventlet.spawn_n(cube, 10)
se.wait()
sc.wait()
```

Comment: Thanks joseph, instead of using spawn_n we can also use spawn with wait directly, ex: t1 = eventlet.spawn(square, 10).wait() works as well.

Comment: Dear Vidyadhar, I do not completely agree. The moment you call t1 = eventlet.spawn(square, 10).wait(), this means the call is still synchronous, maybe if you write : t1.wait() after all spawns i agree.